# Kraken Futures API. Get Orders history

Tags: node.js, kraken.com

I need to load all the orders I had by API. Currently I found only one way to get Fills snapshot by websockets but there is not enough info about orders. I see order ID there, but can't find endpoint to get details of Order by ID. Also I found "Order Events" which is also poor of data about Order. The API is really messy and have a lot of changes frequently, but still, maybe there is something hidden or still available to be able to get normal history with full info about Orders by API. Thanks!